# How to let P4 new worksapce find what have been downloaded already?

Tags: perforce

My question is:
I have downloaded all files before, then I switch to a new P4 Account, So I got a new workspace. But how can I use the file I have downloaded already with my new workspace? Do I need to redownload all files?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple user accounts that are logged in on the same machine can use the same workspace.  If you're using the same physical files, you should be using the same workspace rather than creating a new one which shares its `Root`.

If you have a **copy** of the files from the original workspace and want to use those to bootstrap the new workspace, you can do this with `p4 flush` and `p4 clean`.  But you do **not** want to define multiple workspaces on the server that share the same physical `Root` on the client; this will *never work well*, just like you don't want to use multiple physical `Root`s with a single workspace definition.  They should **always** be one-to-one.